# gem attr_encrypted doesn't work with rails 2.3.8 + bundler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, attr-encrypted

so, when I use [this gem](https://github.com/shuber/attr_encrypted) with the config.gem method it rails 2's environment.rb file, everything is fine.  I can save and read encrypted attributes.

but when I use bundler (the preferred method =D), attr_encrypted suddenly isn't able to read or write any of the encrypted attributes to the database. There are no errors anywhere in the console / log / webpage.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to do:

```
gem "attr_encrypted", :require => nil
```

in the gemfile

and then do

```
require "attr_encrypted"
```

somewhere in environment.rb after `Bundler` has required the other gems.